# Criar Schema com o Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5

Existe alguma forma de eu fazer com que o próprio Laravel 5.1 crie um banco de dados conforme não existir este banco? ( pode ser ou em uma tabela de um banco master ou de da própria lista de bd's mesmo... tanto faz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Será algo como:

```
 DB::getConnection()->statement('CREATE DATABASE :schema', ['schema' => $schemaName]);
```